# sqoop import to hive failing with java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a sqoop import script to load data from Oracle to Hive.

**Query**

```
sqoop-import -D mapred.child.java.opts="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev /../dev/abc" -D mapreduce.job.queuename="queue_name"   \
--connect ${jdbc_url}  \
--username ${username} \
--password ${password} \
--query  "$query" \
--target-dir  ${target_hdfs_dir} \
--delete-target-dir \
--fields-terminated-by ${hiveFieldsDelimiter} \
--hive-import ${o_write} \
--null-string '' \
--hive-table ${hiveTableName} \
$split_opt \
$numMapper\
```

**Logs**

> 18/02/01 12:38:45 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Create statement: CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_test.test` ( `USR_ID` STRING, `ENT_TYPE`
>   STRING, `VAL` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2018/02/01
>   12:38:45' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054' LINES
>   TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE 18/02/01 12:38:45 DEBUG
>   hive.TableDefWriter: Load statement: LOAD DATA INPATH
>   'hdfs://nn-sit/user/test_tmp' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE `db_test.test`
>   18/02/01 12:38:45 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into
>   Hive 18/02/01 12:38:45 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Using in-process Hive
>   instance. 18/02/01 12:38:45 DEBUG util.SubprocessSecurityManager:
>   Installing subprocess security manager
>
> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   jar:file:/path/demoapp/lib/demoapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>   OK Time taken: 2.189 seconds Loading data to table db_test.test
>   **Failed with exception java.net.UnknownHostException: nn-dev FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask**

**Observations:**

1. We recently migrated to new cluster. The new namenode is `nn-sit`,
   earlier it was `nn-dev`. Can somebody enlighten me where from Sqoop is
   reading the older namenode name `nn-dev` as shown in the error
   message:

> Failed with exception java.net.UnknownHostException: nn-dev

2. It is successful in importing the data from Oracle to the target
   `hdfs path: hdfs://nn-sit/user/test_tmp`. However it is failing while
   loading to the Hive table.
3. The below individual command is successful from beeline.

   LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://nn-sit/user/test_tmp' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE `db_test.test`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you may have to check if value of fs.defaultFS is correct in core-site.xml

Comment: Thanks Shubhangi for checking this. However I checked the property and it is set to nn-sit. Any other suggestions?